# How can I make my JS script calls in Magento appear on one line?

Tags: javascript, magento

I am doing various modifications to my NGINX Magento server and part of this is to do front end optimisations

I am currently using a CDN plugin to host my JS but Magento always calls JS lines (huge massive calls to JS libariries which looks ugly in the code view) that I want to combine to one line.

I know you can use Admin > Developer to merge JS files but I dont want to do this. I want to make this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/prototype/validation.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/js.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/mage/translate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/mage/cookies.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/product.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/configurable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
```

Change to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/prototype/validation.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/builder.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/effects.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/dragdrop.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/controls.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/scriptaculous/slider.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/js.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/form.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/mage/translate.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/mage/cookies.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/product.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/varien/configurable.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/calendar/calendar.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="http://dz36xlwnpud7z.cloudfront.net/cdn/210393/js/calendar/calendar-setup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you share why removing newlines would be considered a useful optimization?

Comment: where is the optimization in putting it in one line? The number of requests stays the same. What you want to do is merge your files into fewer ones, ideally a single one. Also you might want to try to us async for your calls to boost performance.

Comment: There are thousands of references with making your final HTML document sit one one line as much as possible reduce the document size. I don't want to state this already. I am after a solution not a consultation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is what you're looking for. I tested this with Magento 1.9.2.1.

In this file `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head`, function `getCssJsHtml()` on line 210 character 112-119 you'll find this `. "\n"`. Remove that from the function and your JS files will be rendered in one line as you requested.

Keep in mind not to modify core files but to extend the class and override only this function to maintain rest of functionality.

Comment: Thanks. This has resolved my query. I have done and replaced the files and results were instant! Thanks again

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it helped :)